# Context initialization failed error while starting the kaa service

Tags: kaa

I am getting ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed error while starting the kaa service. I am using the instructions in the following document. (version = kaa-node-0.10.0.deb)

http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/

Any pointer to solve this?

## ERROR

2016-12-10 05:13:31,499 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.messaging.MessagingService org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.AbstractAdminService.messagingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messagingService' defined in class path resource [admin-web/WEB-INF/adminContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Answer (score 0):

You have some trouble with sql database. You use MariaDb or PostgreSQL? Please check configurations in **kaa/server/common/dao/src/main/resources/sql-dao.properties** and **kaa/server/node/src/main/resources/admin-dao.properties** files.
If you use MariaDb, maybe you forgot to create user in database. Please use [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/#third-party-components), part where example about creation of user.